# how I can create a context menu with bootstrap when clicking on a marker google maps?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps

I saw an example with bootstrap to right click:
http://jsfiddle.net/X9tgY/789/

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="doc_body">test zone click right here</div>
<div id="map"></div>
<ul id="contextMenu" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" style="display:none" >
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Seguimiento</a></li>
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Enviar comando</a></li>
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Historial de recorrido</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Productividad de motorista</a></li>
</ul>
```

but I have not managed to get to right click on the maker display the contextmenu of bootstrap: http://jsfiddle.net/38jL3drq/3/

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'rightclick', function() {
        console.log(marker);
        console.log($(marker)[0]);
        //Contexmenu($(marker)[0]);

  });
```

I want to right click on the marker me out something like this:
[image]

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

1. First you must create marker without optimized:

   var our_marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: your_lat_lng, map: map,  optimized: false});
   our_marker.set("id", your_marker_id); //may be you need marker id
2. Now set marker id (probably when you click the right button on marker then you need marker id):

   google.maps.event.addListener(our_marker,  'rightclick', function(mouseEvent) { 
   global_current_right_click_id = our_marker.get("id");
   });
3. Embed jquery livequery plugin. Download from [here](https://github.com/brandonaaron/livequery)
4. Now initilize contex menu:

   $('.gmnoprint').livequery(function(){
                   $(this).contextMenu('contextMenu', 
                   {
                       bindings: {
                           'seguimiento': function(t) {
                               global_current_right_click_id; //clicked marker`s id
   ...........................
                           },
   })
   })